# Transmitting and Receiving messages through RF433 using Raspberry Pico

Tags: pi-pico, micropython

I'm currently working in a new DIY project, where I need to send a message through RF from Raspberry Pico, and receive it in an other Raspberry Pico through RF. I have bought some common RF433 receivers and transmitters (see image below)

I'm using MicroPython.

I have searched Internet to find possible solutions, but didn't manage to find one for Pico. Is it feasible?

Also, is there a library that I can use to send and receive messages through RF433?

Thank you in advance.

[image: RF receiver and transmitter]

Comment: (1) MX-05V is newbie firendly. (2) Arduino video tutorial, libraries, and demo code are easy to find. (3) Pico equivalent is not around, unfortunately. (4) Fortunately the code is not that complicated, so you can try to convert the Arcuino C++ code to Pico MicroPython (the other way around is more difficult, though). If you decided to use MX-05V, you might like to list the simple code and me or others might give a hint on how to convert it to python. PS, I once used use Arduino Decimilla 3V3 SPI RF12B and found it tricky to work with, But 5V MX-05Ｖ is much simpler. / to continue, ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try your proposal to convert Arduino library to RpiPico. Do you have any specific library recommendation?

Comment: Ah, I need to first look at the datasheet, to make sure if my suggestion makes any sense.  433MHz Wireless Modules MX-05 _ HobbyComponents
https://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?t=1324

Comment: I randomly googled and found this library. Now I am checking it out. HCWireless Arduino Library for 433MHz Wireless Tx & Rx modules - HobbyComponents
https://forum.hobbycomponents.com/viewtopic.php?f=58&t=2914

Comment: The HobbyComponents does not provide any MX-05V datasheet. Other shops seems to link another chip: https://components101.com/modules/433-mhz-rf-receiver-module.

Comment: This tutorial looks better: How to use 315Mhz RF Transmitter and Receiver Modules (MX-FS-03V / MX-05V) with Arduino
http://myhowtosandprojects.blogspot.com/2014/01/arduino-rf-transmitter-receiver-mx-fs.html.

Comment: And this looks like a good library: VirtualWire Library VirtualWire, by Mike McCauley (PDF), helps you use very inexpensive wireless radio modules - PJRC
https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_VirtualWire.html

Comment: I will check and I will get back to you

Comment: OK. BTW, documentation is very good: http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/VirtualWire.pdf

Comment: Just now I tried to download VirtualWire in my Windows 10, but no luck. I have no Arduino staff in my PC Windows, and no Arduino in hand. It would be nice if you can installed VirtualWire somewhere and pass me a copy of the source code, then I can skim through it and see if it would be easy just to translate the bare bone part and try it in Rpi Pico MicroPython.

Comment: I have found this VirtualWire library for Pi. Indeed it is not for Pico. Also this source code has a dependency to RPi.GPIO which is not for Pico also. https://quadmeup.com/virtualwire-support-for-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130758/discussion-between-tlfong01-and-antifa).